# Vue - global import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, global

I use

```
import {mapFields} from "vuex-map-fields"
```

in every component.

How can I make this available in every component without having to import it? Is there any risk to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want it globally what you have to do it's inject in the Vue instance
same way that we do when we use vuex

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from './store'

new Vue( {
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h( App )
} );
```

then in any component you can `console.log(this)`; you should be able to see your object

Answer (score 5):

you can use Vue.prototype as follows..

[src/main.js]

```
import { mapFields } from 'vuex-map-fields';
...
Vue.prototype.$mapFields = mapFields;
```

then in any component you can use this.$mapFields(...) function!

[ in any component ]

```
<template>
......
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    ...this.$mapFields({
      userFirstName: 'user.firstName',
      userLastName: 'user.lastName',
    }),
  },
};
</script>
```

There is no risks in this code...